# Find how many times different adjacent words exist in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I'm trying to write a function which can tell you how many times different adjacent character exit in a string. i.e LOLOLO have different adjacent words 5 times. I have tried many times but every time I run, I get error:- line 5, in adjacent_numbers
    if c != string[i+1] :
IndexError: string index out of range

```
def adjacent_numbers(string):
    count = 0
    i = 0
    for i,c in enumerate(string):
        if c != string[i+1] :
            count += 1
        i += 1

    return count
```

Comment: Words or characters? If you get an error, add the error in your question's description.

Comment: The values of `i` are filled in for you by the for loop. You can remove `i = 0` and `i += 1`.

Comment: sorry ,It suppose be character

Comment: It seems that what you're trying to do is count the number of groups of characters where each group is as large as possible and all the characters in that group are the same. Is that right? e.g. AABCCC -> 3, AABBAB -> 4. In that case shouldn't you get 6 for LOLOLO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens when you get to the end of the string and ask for the 'next' character which doesn't exist. When `i` is the last index in the string (which it is bound to be at the end of the loop) it doesn't make sense to ask for `string[i+1]`. What you can do is iterate over the string minus the last character using slice notation: `for i, c in enumerate(string[:-1]): ...`

Comment: Glad to hear it! When you see a correct answer that solves your problem you should usually click the check/tick mark on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot index one past the string length, you could slice one from the end with  `string[:-1]`, but you can avoid slicing you can use a for loop and `iter`:

```
s = "LOLOLO"

def adj(s):
    # iter create an iterator
    it, sm = iter(s), 0
    # pull first character and set prev equal to it
    prev = next(it)
    # iterate over all bar the first char
    for ch in it:
        # if previous is not equal to current char add 1 to sm
        if ch != prev:
            sm += 1
        # set prev to current char
        prev = ch
    # catch last char
    return sm + (prev != ch)
```

Output:

```
In [3]: adj(s)
Out[3]: 5
```

You can also cheat a bit with enumerate, you can using slicing which will not cause an IndexError, you can also use the builtin `sum` function to so the counting:

```
def adj(s):
    return sum(ch != s[i:i+1] and i < len(s) for i, ch in enumerate(s, 1))

print(adj(s))
```

enumerate also takes a start arg which is one in this case so we start indexing at the second char.

Applying the same logic to your own loop:

```
def adjacent_numbers(string):
    count = 0
    for i,c in enumerate(string, 1):
        if i < len(s) and c != string[i:i+1]:
            count += 1
    return count
```

`i` was not needed in your code either so I removed it, you don't need to initialise variables in python, `i` will work fine in the loop.

Comment: A clever idea but a bit hard to read and certainly not suitable for a beginner who can barely understand for loops. The short variable names don't help. Why not `count` instead of `sm`?

Comment: I'm new to python, so I don't quite understand how that code works.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: No worries,  pretty much everything in the answer is pretty basic stuff, `sum` would be the idiomatic way to write your for loop and iter is a good way to avoid slicing and creating more copies of data. The first code would be the best approach from an efficiency perspective as indexing/slicing is much slower than just iterating

Answer (score 0):

Code golfing...

```
import operator
s = 'LOLOLO'
sum(map(operator.ne, s, s[1:]))
```